# Half-max isocline in log-log scale

Tags: plotting

I have a function and I would like to contour plot with half-max in log-log (in base 10 )scale.

```
   f[i1_,i2_]:= 87.6293 + 1.30282*10^6/( 194.574 + 8439.54/(1 + 3.2176*10^9 i1^3.8546) + 18567.7/(  1 + 157.95 i2^1.39834))
```

and half max is

```
h=3380.54
```

This kind of plot is expected

[image]

Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper function `g` to transform from log to natural space, then plot contours of that function. Using your definition of `f` from OP:

```
Clear[g]
g[x_, y_] := f[10^x, 10^y]

ContourPlot[g[x, y] == 3380.54, {x, -4, 2}, {y, -1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you so much.